# WSS 3.0 Give user contribute access to a list but preventing them from seeing it?

Tags: list, workflow, permissions

I'm working on a workflow in WSS 3.0 that involves copying an item from list #1 to list #2.

The issue I'm having is that the user that initiates the workflow on list #1 must have contribute permission on list #2 for the workflow to work but the user must not be able to see or find list #2.

Is there any way of letting a user create items in a list through a workflow but not being able to see it?

I didn't think this would be a problem when I started setting up the workflow as I somehow thought I could run a workflow as a specific user but it looks like that isn't possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer, right click on list #2 and select Properties.  Click on the Settings tab and select the option Hide from Browsers and click OK.  This will remove the list from the interface.

Those working with the data in that list will need hooks into it or separate web part pages with access to the list.

Comment: Will it prevent a call to webservices? I feel it's only hidding the list, not protecting its access, isn't it ?

Comment: It is still there but much harder to access without the full URL. If the users never know it exists then they are unlikely to find it. Workflows will still function.

Comment: Awesome! This will solve it. Thanks a lot! I understand it's not 100% secure but for what this will be used for it's perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2cd workflow an run it from the first workflow. As a secondary workflow it will run under the system account not the users account. I usual name these workflow starting with "x_" I build the system to hide workflow starting these characters so they are never seen by end users.